# Fixme incompatible with two-column?

Tags: two-column, incompatibility, fixme

I wanted to use Fixme together with my two-column layout, but the output of Fixme looks broken, as if the margins are too small or so.

See example:

[image]

Example code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est 

\fxerror{this is only Lorem ipsum}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In two column mode the size reserved for margin notes is very narrow (4pt). Say

```
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{24pt}
```

(or some other length you find fit) in your document preamble.

Answer (score 11):

As the margins are very small in twocolumn mode, you can switch to another layout:

```
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{
    status=draft,
    author={Note},
    layout=inline, % also try footnote or pdfnote
    theme=color
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but egreg's work around is more usable for me, even though your approach seems to be the "right way"™ to do it in the grand scheme of things. +1

Comment: sure, no problem. also there are more layouts you could try that don't change the layout of your document (especially `pdfnote`)